# Reading first line of each file getting aborted at binary files

Tags: haskell, file-read

I am trying to read first line of each file in current directory:

```
import System.IO(IOMode(ReadMode), withFile, hGetLine)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesFileExist, getFileSize)
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import Control.Monad(filterM)

readFirstLine :: FilePath -> IO String
readFirstLine fp = withFile fp ReadMode System.IO.hGetLine

getAbsoluteDirContents :: String -> IO [FilePath]
getAbsoluteDirContents dir = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents dir
    return $ map (dir </>) contents

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- get a list of all files & dirs
    contents <- getAbsoluteDirContents "."
    -- filter out dirs
    files <- filterM doesFileExist contents
    -- read first line of each file
    d <- mapM readFirstLine files
    print d
```

It is compiling and running but getting aborted with following error at a binary file:

```
mysrcfile: ./aBinaryFile: hGetLine: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

I want to detect and avoid such files and go on to next file.

Comment: A binary file has no "lines", so that indeed makes sense. What would you return in that case?

Comment: I want to skip such files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary file is a file that contains byte sequences that can not be decoded to a valid string. But a binary file is not different from a text file if you do not inspect its content.

It might be better to use an "It's **E**asier to **A**sk **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission (EAFP)" approach: we try to read the first line, and if that fails, we ignore the output.

```
import Control.Exception(catch, IOException)
import System.IO(IOMode(ReadMode), withFile, hGetLine)

readFirstLine :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
readFirstLine fp = withFile fp ReadMode $
    \h -> (catch (fmap Just (hGetLine h))
        ((const :: a -> IOException -> a) (return Nothing)))
```

For a `FilePath` this returns an `IO (Maybe String)`. If we run the `IO (Maybe String)`, it will return a `Just x` with `x` the first line if it can read such file, and `Nothing` if an `IOException` was encoutered.

We can then make use of [**`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) to obtain the `Just x`s:

```
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- get a list of all files & dirs
    contents <- getAbsoluteDirContents "."
    -- filter out dirs
    files <- filterM doesFileExist contents
    -- read first line of each file
    d <- mapM readFirstLine files
    print (catMaybes d)
```

or you can make use of [**`mapMaybeM :: Monad m => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> [a] -> m [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.18/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:mapMaybeM) in the [**`extra`** package [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra/) that will automate that work for you.